# while submitting data in first form blank object is getting created for second form django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

views.py

```
def crave_view(request):
    if (request.method=="POST"):

        form1=CraveDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        form2 = CraveReplyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print form1
        print form2

        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():

            crave_made = form1.save(commit=False)
            crave_made.person = request.user
            crave_made.save()  
            reply = form2.save(commit=False)
            reply.person=request.user
            reply.crave = crave_made
            reply.save()

            #login(request,crave_made.username,form1.clean_password2())
            messages.success(request, 'You Registered Successfully')

            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/details/')
        else:
            print form1
            print form2

            messages.error(request, 'Please enter all required fields')                     
    else:                    
        form2 = CraveReplyForm()
        form1=CraveDataForm()  


    return render(request, "crave/crave.html", { 'form1' : form1, 'form2' : form2 })
```

models.py

```
class crave_data(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post=models.TextField(blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post



class comments(models.Model):

    crave=models.ForeignKey(crave_data)
    reply=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reply
```

forms.py

```
class CraveDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = crave_data
        exclude=['date', 'password1', 'password2', 'username', 'person']

class CraveReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = comments
        exclude=['date', 'crave', 'password1', 'password2', 'username']
```

crave.html

```
<form class="horizontal-form" role="form" action="." method="post"  style="padding: 10px;">
           {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group" >


                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form1.post.label_tag }}{{ form1.post }} <br /><br>   
                        </div>
                        </div>      
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="crave" />
                    </form>


        <form class="horizontal-form" role="form" action="." method="post"  style="padding: 10px;">
           {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group" >
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form2.reply.label_tag }} {{ form2.reply }}   </br> </br>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="reply" />
        </form>
```

i want to submit data of form one only, but the thing is happening that for form2 i.e. for comment blank object is getting created, its due to a foriegn key i given in comment class.
i dont want the blank object getting created for form2. The data should get saved for form2 after clicking on the submit button of form2. And i can not remove foreign key relationship from there also. reply should get submitted for that relative crave only. and data should get submitted independantlly.

I dont want data to be saved for both form after clicking on submit button of one form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use one view function for two different actions.

You should do view for add/edit Crave objects like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def crave_edit(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(crave_data, pk=id) if id else None
    if instance and instance.person != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=CraveDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            crave_made = form.save(commit=False)
            crave_made.person = request.user
            crave_made.save()                    
    else:                    
        form=CraveDataForm(instance=instance)  

    return render(request, "crave/crave_edit.html", {'form' : form})
```

Once again, you shouldn't mix add/edit Crave with add comments. You can't add comment to non-exist entity:

```
@login_required
def crave_view(request, id):
    crave = get_object_or_404(crave_data, pk=id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=CraveReplyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            reply = form.save(commit=False)
            reply.person=request.user
            reply.crave = crave
            reply.save()                    
    else:                    
        form=CraveReplyForm()  

    return render(request, "crave/crave_view.html", {'crave': crave, 'form' : form})
```

And please note that names for models should be capitalised, without underlines - "crave_data" is bad style

Comment: no i want both post and comment on single page only,,,,,,,,

Comment: Can i render to same template in bote view?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. It will be two view functions, each process self form and if request.METHOD not POST generate two empty forms.

Comment: Can you post the answer,,,, sorry to trouble you but i am quite new to django

Comment: Hay i am getting this error crave_view() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Hay i am getting ValueError  invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
my url is  url(r'^reply_get/(?P<id>.*)$', 'crave_view'),

Comment: hay i am getting the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'person'"  hay help me.

Comment: getting the above error in this line if instance.person != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied()

Comment: change it to "if instance and instance.person != request.user:"

Comment: while i print instance i am getting None,,,,,,,,,i want to call crave object of another view to crave_edit view

Answer (score 0):

You can make the foreign key field optional in Django model

Try this way,

```
crave=models.ForeignKey(crave_data, blank=True, null=True)
```

If you want submit the forms independently. then put the hidden input field in one form and separate the form logic in view based on hidden input. Like this,

```
if 'hidden_input' in request.POST.keys():
```